# Is it possible to add a textbox inside a checkboxlist control in C# winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkboxlist

I have a checkboxlist control in my windows forms application that i am building using c#.I am using this checkboxlist to add or remove certain attributes from a product.The functionality i want is that when i click on any one of the checkboxes, i want a textbox to appear beside the checkbox so that I can enter the value of that attribute and save that value somehow.

Please Help.

Comment: What you mean inside the check box

Comment: beside checkboxlist not inside checkbox

Answer (score 0):

You will need to Create  Custom control to do that. (Inherit the Control add custom functionality). Or simply use WPF

Comment: how simple is it to use WPF? Can I add a WPF control inside my winform??